# Add percentage to the monthly function

Tags: javascript, function, input

I have a script that takes an Estimated total (calcOrderTotal which is outputted to an html input) and divides it by 36 and 24 and 12 months (which are also then outputted to their own html input).  How can I add 17% to the cost of the 36, 24, and 12 month costs?  I have attempted to create functions that do so (calcMonthly(total), calcMonthlyPercent(), and calcMonthlyTotal()), but they don't work.

My JS:

```
function calcOrderTotal() {

var orderTotal = 0;

var productSubtotal = $("#product-subtotal").val() || 0;
var serverPrice = $('.server-radio:checked').val() || 0;
var equipmentPrice = $('.equipment-radio:checked').val() || 0;
var underTotal = $("#under-box").val() || 0;

var orderTotal = parseFloat(CleanNumber(productSubtotal)) + parseFloat(CleanNumber(serverPrice)) + parseFloat(CleanNumber(equipmentPrice));    

$("#order-total").val(CommaFormatted(orderTotal));

$("#fc-price").attr("value", orderTotal);
if (orderTotal > 0) {
    calcMonthly(orderTotal);
}

}

function calcMonthly(total) {

var pmt1 = total / 36;
var pmt2 = total / 24;
var pmt3 = total / 12;

}

function calcMonthlyPercent() {

var pmt1percent = pmt1 * .17;
var pmt2percent = pmt2 * .17;
var pmt3percent = pmt3 * .17;

}

function calcMonthlyTotal () {

var pmt1total = pmt1 + pmt1percent;
var pmt2total = pmt2 + pmt2percent;
var pmt3total = pmt3 + pmt3percent;

$("#monthly-36").val(CommaFormatted(pmt1total));
$("#monthly-24").val(CommaFormatted(pmt2total));
$("#monthly-12").val(CommaFormatted(pmt3total));

}
```

The HTML inputs are:

```
<span><b>Estimate:</b><br></span> 
<input type="text" class="total-box" value="$0" id="order-total" disabled="disabled" name="order-total"></input><br><br><br>
<span><b>Estimated 36 Month Lease:</b><br></span>
<input type="text" class="total-box" value="$0" id="monthly-36" disabled="disabled" name="monthly-36"></input><br><br><br>
<span><b>Estimated 24 Month Lease:</b><br></span>
<input type="text" class="total-box" value="$0" id="monthly-24" disabled="disabled" name="monthly-24"></input><br><br><br>
<span><b>Estimated 12 Month Lease:</b><br></span>
<input type="text" class="total-box" value="$0" id="monthly-12" disabled="disabled" name="monthly-12"></input>
```

Comment: You are not returning anything from calcMonthly()..  In your calcMonthlyPercent(), your pmt1,pmt2, and pmnt3 are undefined.. You need to brush up on your JavaScript basics before attempting such a problem

Comment: I don't know anything about Javascript, that's why I'm asking here.  I did not originally write this script, I'm just trying to modify it per my boss's requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$("#monthly-36").val(CommaFormatted(orderTotal/36*1.17));
$("#monthly-24").val(CommaFormatted(orderTotal/24*1.17));
$("#monthly-12").val(CommaFormatted(orderTotal/12*1.17));
```

I advise you to really try to understand what is going on in the code. Take up a JavaScript course. If you try to mimic other code without understand it you will end up digging yourself quite a big hole from which even experienced people might have trouble digging you out of.